Swinging Magnetic Attracted to Batteries
I have a pendulum in which the Bob is a permanent magnet.  The circuit and batteries are hidden inside the base. The problem is that the permanent magnet is attracted to the batteries and slows the swing resulting in a lower amplitude swing. I know I can move the batteries farther away but I'm stuck on this design. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening? Are there batteries that are less magnetic? I can't seem to find anything and not sure if I want to pay that kind of money for a Numetal shield. Thanks.

It's mumetal (for mu referring to the magnetic field properties of materials)

Based on a sample of exactly one piece, the one I happen to have laying on the desk in front of me, pouch-type Li batteries are less ferromagnetic than cylindrical 18650 types.
The one I have is 3.7V 2100mAh rated and only the thin metal connections at one end appear to be strongly magnetic.
They are also slim, which could help with design aesthetics.
